# Calling Powershell script from windows service written in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-services

I have a windows service written in C# and it calls a powershell script inside it using the code below:

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        powershell.AddCommand("Invoke-Command")
          .AddParameter("ComputerName", remoteComputer)
          .AddParameter("FilePath", scriptPath)
          .AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[] { credential,IndexList,FilePath });
        psOutput = powershell.Invoke();
    }
    runspace.Close();
}
```

I keep on getting the error below:

`Connecting to remote server <computername> failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`

Though the same code works if this is run as console application but I am getting this error while running it as windows service.

Am I doing something wrong here?, or there is another way to call powershell script in windows service?

Comment: User, under which windows sservice is working, doesn't have access permissions to whatever you are trying to access.

Comment: Windows service is being run as a local user and that is admin as well and if this is permission related problem why does this work when this is run as a console application?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are doin it right but the remote computer is not configured properly.
Try to execute the Commandlet

```
Enable-PSRemoting
```

on the target computer in an elevated powershell.
That should configure the WinRm service to enable remoting and adds an firewall rule for remoting. 
For more information look here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/p
owershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/p%20owershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7)

Comment: `WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer`.- Get this after executing above command and the reason I think this is not the problem, when I run console app and that is also accessing remote computer that works.

Comment: maybe a silly question, but is the user which is running the service in the Administrators group on the remote target?

Comment: Yeah, Actually I am targetting the same system from which I am running so the remote target is the machine where service is running and yes, the user is admin.

Comment: have you tried checking the 'interact with Desktop' checkbox (which is considered as bad practice) To allow the service interact with other contexts?

Comment: I don't know why, but what you suggested worked and now service is able to call powershell script on remote computer. Thanks a lot.